# How to select specific Map in List from a value in Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering how one can get a specific map in a list from a value inside the map. For example, if I have:

```
List<Map> aList = [{'id':'1'},{'id':'8'},{'id':'31'}];
```

How can I get the Map whose id == 8?

I am trying it on DartPad, but I always get an error when assigning the result to a List and have found no answers on how to properly assign a WhereIterable to a List.

```
void main() {
  List map = [
    {'id':'pez', 'num': 25},
    {'id':'lava', 'num': 3},
    {'id':'mar', 'num': 81},
    {'id':'pan', 'num': 33},
    {'id':'lava', 'num': 73},
  ];

  List otherMap = map.where((item) => item['id'] == 'mar');
  print(otherMap);
}
//ERROR:
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'WhereIterable<dynamic>': type 'WhereIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 2):

One must use the `.toList()` method after `where()`

```
List otherMap = map.where((item) => item['id'] == 'mar').toList();
```